# Is it possible to bypass required fields when using {freeform:submit_previous}

Tags: solspace-freeform, php

I've got an issue with Solspace Freeform whereby the required field error message is being triggered if the user chooses to go the previous page without entering any information on the current page. Is there any way to bypass this?

I already have a custom extension created which uses the `freeform_module_insert_begin` hook and contained within is a conditional for submitting to a previous page. Is there a function, or something, that I can use here to bypass the required field?

```
<?php
function checkup_method( $inputs, $entry_id, $form_id, $obj ) {
    if ( ee()->extensions->last_call !== FALSE ) {
        $inputs = ee()->extensions->last_call;
    }

    if ( get_class( $obj ) == 'Freeform' ) {

        $submit = 'submit';
        if ( isset( $_POST['submit_to_previous'] ) )
            $submit = 'previous';           

        if ( $submit == 'previous' ) {

            // Custom code           

        }

    }

    return $inputs;

}
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get around this by hooking into `freeform_module_validate_end`. The hook in my question runs after the validation so I couldn't do anything with that. It simply clears any field errors on submitting to the previous page.

```
function checkup_override_required( $errors, $obj ) {

    if (ee()->extensions->last_call !== FALSE) {
        $errors = ee()->extensions->last_call;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit_to_previous'] ) ) {
        // Clear errors on submit to previous
        $obj->field_errors = array(); // This needs to be an array
    }

    return $errors;
}
```